# Form become blank intermittently

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a web-crawler developed using webbrowser control.  Sometimes it works fine – it reaches login page  home page  catalog menu page  product detail page  come back to catalog menu page. But at certain times, it just reaches upto the home page, afterwards it gives a blank page.  It doesn’t get the required element ids.

I tried various suggestions as given below…  They didn’t help. The interesting fact is this issue is an intermittent issue. Any thoughts what need to be done to overcome this intermittent issue?

Note: I won’t be able to share the url of the site since it is an intranet site.

**REFERENCES**

1. [Getting HTML body content in WinForms WebBrowser after body onload event executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368778/getting-html-body-content-in-winforms-webbrowser-after-body-onload-event-execute)
2. [Webbrowser Control Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495944/webbrowser-control-limitations)
3. [Why is the Webbrowser control DocumentComplete event fired for top level frame first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080224/why-is-the-webbrowser-control-documentcomplete-event-fired-for-top-level-frame-f)
4. [WebBrowser control = wait for page load to complete in an Assembly](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9e5d265c-8771-433c-a2aa-91b4eeb1d684/webbrowser-control-wait-for-page-load-to-complete-in-an-assembly?forum=winforms)

**CODE**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = null;
    private ListBox listBox1 = null;
    List<string> visitedUrls = new List<string>();
    List<string> visitedProducts = new List<string>();
    bool isFirstPage = true;
    string clickType = String.Empty;
    bool isUnvisitedProductExist = true;

    private void ExerciseApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        #region Listbox Data Filling

        if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Start--" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count == 2)
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(1);
            }

            listBox1.Items.Add("Now--" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        WriteLogFunction(" -----------------------------------------------");

        #region Login
        //Check whether login page
        if (isFirstPage)
        {
            HtmlElement logonId = this.wb.Document.GetElementById("logonId");
            HtmlElement password = this.wb.Document.GetElementById("logonPassword");
            HtmlElement btnLogin = this.wb.Document.GetElementById("WC_AccountDisplay_links_2");
            if (logonId != null && password != null && btnLogin != null)
            {
                logonId.InnerText = ConfigValues.userName;
                password.InnerText = ConfigValues.passwordText;
                isFirstPage = false;

                //Call click for login
                btnLogin.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        bool isClickCalled = false;

        #region Specific Product Details
        int catalogElementIterationCounter = 0;
        var elementsToConsider = wb.Document.All;
        bool isMenuPage = false;
        foreach (HtmlElement e1 in elementsToConsider)
        {
            catalogElementIterationCounter++;
            string x = e1.TagName;
            String idStr = e1.GetAttribute("id");

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idStr))
            {

                //Each Product Navigation
                if (idStr.Contains("catalogEntry_img"))
                {

                    isMenuPage = true;
                    string productUrl = e1.GetAttribute("href");
                    if (!visitedProducts.Contains(productUrl))
                    {
                        WriteLogFunction("p__" + productUrl);
                        isUnvisitedProductExist = true;
                        visitedProducts.Add(productUrl);
                        isClickCalled = true;
                        clickType = "Product";

                        e1.InvokeMember("Click");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isMenuPage)
            {
                //Even after traversing the page, there is no unvisited product pending.
                //So good to go for next page
                if (catalogElementIterationCounter == elementsToConsider.Count - 1)
                {
                    isUnvisitedProductExist = false;
                }
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region Menu Page
        if (!isClickCalled)
        {
            #region Time Delay
            try
            {
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                if (!wb.IsDisposed)
                {
                    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                        if (wb.IsDisposed || DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds > 2)
                        {
                            // Time limit break and dispose break
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLogFunction(ex.Message);
                //Supress the exception
            }
            #endregion

            int menuPageIterationCounter = 0;
            bool isMatchFound = false;

            WriteLogFunction("Count-" + wb.Document.All.Count);

            var elementsInMenuPage = wb.Document.All;
            foreach (HtmlElement e1 in elementsInMenuPage)
            {
                menuPageIterationCounter++;

                string x = e1.TagName;
                String idStr = e1.GetAttribute("id");

                WriteLogFunction("Before--"+idStr);

                #region time Delay
                try
                {
                    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                    if (!wb.IsDisposed)
                    {
                        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                        {
                           System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                            if (wb.IsDisposed || DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds > 50)
                            {
                                // Time limit break and dispose break
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteLogFunction(ex.Message);
                    //Supress the exception
                }
                #endregion

                WriteLogFunction("After--" + idStr);

                //Main Menu Item Navigation
                if (idStr.Contains("WC_CachedHeaderDisplay_links"))
                {
                    WriteLogFunction("*******INSIDE");
                    string url = e1.GetAttribute("href");

                    string latestUrl = String.Empty;
                    if (visitedUrls.Count > 0)
                    {
                        latestUrl = visitedUrls[visitedUrls.Count - 1];
                    }
                    WriteLogFunction("L__" + latestUrl);

                    WriteLogFunction("isUnvisitedProductExist__" + isUnvisitedProductExist.ToString());

                    if (visitedUrls.Contains(url) && isUnvisitedProductExist)
                    {
                        if (latestUrl == url)
                        {
                            isMatchFound = true;
                            clickType = "Menu";
                            WriteLogFunction("u1__" + url);
                            e1.InvokeMember("Click");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!visitedUrls.Contains(url))
                    {
                        isMatchFound = true;
                        //Reset visited Products
                        visitedProducts = new List<string>();
                        visitedUrls.Add(url);

                        clickType = "Menu";
                        WriteLogFunction("u2__" + url);
                        e1.InvokeMember("Click");
                        break;
                    }


                    if (!isMatchFound && (menuPageIterationCounter == elementsInMenuPage.Count - 1))
                    {

                        //wb.Navigate(websiteUrl);
                        //Application.Exit();
                        //Environment.Exit(0);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        #endregion


    }


    public Form1()
    {

        // listBox1
        listBox1 = new ListBox();
        listBox1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        listBox1.Size = new Size(500, 50);
        this.Controls.Add(listBox1);

        // Web Browser
        wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Location = new Point(10, 80);
        wb.Size = new Size(900, 900);
        //wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(ExerciseApp);
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Url = new Uri(ConfigValues.websiteUrl);

        // Form1
        this.Text = "Web Browser Test";
        this.Size = new Size(950, 950);
        this.Controls.Add(wb);

        this.Load += Form1_Load;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.wb.DocumentCompleted += delegate
        {
            // DocumentCompleted is fired before window.onload and body.onload
            this.wb.Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
            {
                // Defer this to make sure all possible onload event handlers got fired
                System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("window.onload was fired, can access DOM!");
                    ExerciseApp(null, null);

                }, null);
            });
        };
        this.wb.Navigate(ConfigValues.websiteUrl);
    }

    private void WriteLogFunction(string strMessage)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
        {
            w.WriteLine("\r\n{0} {1} ", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), strMessage);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: You should replace all those regions with well named Methods.  The code would be more self documenting and a little bit less smart-UI.

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610197/async-await-implementation-of-webbrowser-class-for-net

Comment: Windows replaces your main window with the "ghost" window when your UI thread stops responding to notifications.  Plenty of opportunities for that in this code.  [No need to run this code on the UI thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/17034).